# Truffle and npm not working on powershell

Tags: npm, truffle

I am not able to use truffle or npm commands on powershell even though I have it installed, powershell hangs when I use npm init while truffle is not recognized by powershell at all. I have uninstalled and reinstalled truffle many times but to no avail.

For Npm I have no idea how to remove it, after typing the uninstall npm, I could still access its version.

Here is my npm version:

> PS C:\Users\user> npm version
>   { user: '1.0.0',
>     npm: '5.6.0',
>     ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
>     cldr: '31.0.1',
>     http_parser: '2.7.0',
>     icu: '59.1',
>     modules: '57',
>     nghttp2: '1.25.0',
>     node: '8.9.4',
>     openssl: '1.0.2n',
>     tz: '2017b',
>     unicode: '9.0',
>     uv: '1.15.0',
>     v8: '6.1.534.50',
>     zlib: '1.2.11' }

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think it had  to to wth your NPM cache which you should clean, during development 
mine  was corrupted, i had to clean it.

Moralso, from https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell, do install your npm with npm i -S node-powershell.

It should do work.